# How do I sort or move DONE items in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm kind of new to org-mode in Emacs, and I'm investigating if it is suitable to replace Google Tasks for me. Google Tasks offers a "clear completed tasks" action, that removes all tasks that are marked done. Can I do something similar in org-mode with DONE items?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, in org-mode you do archive DONE tasks (within the same file or to a subling file).
You can use <kbd>C-c C-x C-a</kbd> for that.

Please refer the manual [Capture, Refile, Archive](http://orgmode.org/guide/Capture-Refile-Archive.html)