# Remove item older than 2 weeks

Tags: org-mode

I use emacs org-mode to manage work items. Every week, I manually remove all `Done` items older than 2 weeks. Is there an easy way to perform this automatically?

EDIT:

I am currently trying to add a new custom command like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("P" "Show old entries" todo "DONE"
     (
      (org-agenda-files '("c:/git/org/tickets.org"))
      (tags "CLOSED<=\"<-2w>\"")
     )
    ))
  )
```

The filter on the CLOSED timestamp is not working correctly.

Comment: Is [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/354209/how-do-i-sort-or-move-done-items-in-org-mode) of any help ? Related on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392791/archive-all-past-calendar-items-in-org-mode

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but definitively something to investigate. Thanks!